# Managing display with both css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have 3 elements as memory, history and keypad.By default the keypad is open. While clicking on a memoryIcon, memory opens and while clicking on a historyIcon, history opens. When the browser resizes, the keypad should be opened but memory and history should be closed. In my code, when I resize the browser, the keypad would be opened but when I resize back, the memory or history is open! How can I solve this bug?
Here is my css media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    #keypad {
        display: flex !important
    }

    #memory {
        display: none !important
    }

    #history {
        display: none !important
    }
}
```

and the onclick events in app.js file:

```
_elm.historyIcon.onclick = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        historyPad.style.display = "flex";
        memory.style.display = "none";
        keypad.style.display = "none";
    }

    _elm.mBtn.onclick = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        memory.style.display = "flex";
        keypad.style.display = "none";
        historyPad.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: what about other CSS? could you please share them?

Comment: If I understand correctly you're resizing it and it work at beginning but when you resize it broke . Maybe you should add another @ media to ensure it won't do it like @media 800 so when you resize it will check it again

Comment: I addd another media query but the onclick events stop working.

Comment: it stops working because the `!important` in css

Comment: if I remove !important in css, It would not change anything when the brwoser resizes.